# MySQL: Override configured logging

Tags: mysql, linux, logging

I am doing some PHP / MySQL work as a regular user on a server, sharing mysqld with the live webserver on the same server. This mysqld instance is configured to either not log or to log remotely, which is a hassle as I need the logs for development. Is there any way to override the mysqld configuration **for only my user** without getting root involved? Even enabling the logging per-script (PHP) or per-directory (.htaccess maybe, can Apache do that?) would be fine.

Thanks.